# How do I use TextInput for WatchOS in swiftUI

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, swiftui

Typically I would use `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions()` to show the TextInput field. But this isn't available in swiftUI because it is a function of WKInterfaceController. Do I have to use the WKInterfaceController for this? 
I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be done through a [TextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield) in SwiftUI.

Comment: So simple and works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Although I'm using TextField successfully in WatchOS I can't find how to add suggestions to the input.  Any pointers?

Comment: Does anyone know which is the convention or Apple recommend way? TextField or traditional WatchKit text input controller? I've designed my Textfield so it looks like a button anyway, but I'd love to know what the Apple way is for small screens.

Comment: @Edison Since WatchOS 9 you can use TextFieldLink for this purposes

Answer (score 11):

You can use extension for View in SwiftUI:

```
extension View {
    typealias StringCompletion = (String) -> Void
    
    func presentInputController(withSuggestions suggestions: [String], completion: @escaping StringCompletion) {
        WKExtension.shared()
            .visibleInterfaceController?
            .presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: suggestions,
                                        allowedInputMode: .plain) { result in
                
                guard let result = result as? [String], let firstElement = result.first else {
                    completion("")
                    return
                }
                
                completion(firstElement)
            }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            presentInputController()
        }, label: {
            Text("Press this button")
        })
    }
    
    private func presentInputController() {
        presentInputController(withSuggestions: []) { result in
            // handle result from input controller
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: should I just be able to call this from my ContentView? I added this extension beneath the `struct ContentView: View` block, and I'm trying to call it from `Button(action: { presentInputControler(..) })` but when I click the button in preview, nothing happens.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I've added an example to the answer how to use this extension

Answer (score 0):

In WatchOS 9 now we have [TextFieldLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfieldlink)

Instead of using TextField you can use any view as a button for opening text input

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(value)
            TextFieldLink {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            } onSubmit: { value in
                self.value = value
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment - however does this work for you on watchOS 10.1 beta? It closes itself for me on the beta for some reason, can you confirm?