# Dictation input from SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchkit

I'm building my first watchOS app, and I'm new to Swift but loving it so far.

I'm trying to create a button that, when pressed, starts listening in dictation mode. I've seen this done in other watchOS apps (e.g. Drafts).

Is this possible in SwiftUI alone (e.g. via some modifier of `TextField`), or do I need to bridge into UIKit?

If only the latter is possible, I've tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66350000/633406) but clicking the button doesn't seem to do anything. What am I missing?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            presentInputController(withSuggestions: ["testing"], completion: {(answer) -> Void in })
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    typealias StringCompletion = (String) -> Void
    
    func presentInputController(withSuggestions suggestions: [String], completion: @escaping StringCompletion) {
        WKExtension.shared()
            .visibleInterfaceController?
            .presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: suggestions,
                                        allowedInputMode: .plain) { result in
                
                guard let result = result as? [String], let firstElement = result.first else {
                    completion("")
                    return
                }
                
                completion(firstElement)
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look up articles on interfacing with UIKit

Comment: Yes, and I have. Should I infer from your response that it’s not possible to do it in SwiftUI alone?

Comment: No, SwiftUI is for ui and in its early stages. Anything more than the basics it has to be in uikit. Your code is not correct you are interfacing incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind telling me how, or pointing me to an appropriate article, or giving me a tip for what to search? I keep finding articles about pulling in custom controllers and views, when I just need to call this UIKit function.

Comment: The [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806?noredirect=1#comment123677859_69945806) SO post

Comment: Thanks, but I've read that tutorial several times, and I still don't understand how to use `presentTextInputController` from SwiftUI properly. Are you suggesting I need to create a UIKit View or a UIKit Controller? I'm under the impression all I need to do is access the already-existing `visibleInterfaceController`, as they do in this repo https://github.com/adamjberg/engram/blob/b262e59319068424662adfb24aef83b10b9e065e/ios/engram/engram%20WatchKit%20Extension/DailyView.swift#L17

Comment: @loremipsum Turns out my code works just fine. I was just trying to use it in the preview, when I should have been running the application. Just new to Xcode is all. But, to be clear, I didn't need to do anything else to interface with UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TextField for calling text input view, since WatchOS 9 you can use [TextFieldLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfieldlink)